# mpeg-2 422P@H-14 by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

I want to convert videos to mpeg2 422P Profile H-14 Layer, (422P@H-14), with the use of ffmpeg.
What arguments would i need to use?

I followed the comments in [this forum post](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/345143-mpeg2-MP-ML-with-ffmpeg) to solve my problem. I followed comment 6:

> 422P@H-14 would be `-profile:v 0 -level:v 6`

But it did not work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What didn't work? Did you get any error messages? What is the exact, complete ffmpeg command you used? What are the specs of your source?

Comment: The argument I used to convert videos to mpeg2 422P Profile H-14 Layer 'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -s 1440*1080 -r 30 -profile:v 0 -level:v 6 output.mp4‘. But it  showd that the format profile is Main in mediainfo.